# Get next point toward other point

Tags: java, math, vector

I can't understand the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm enough to write it in Java (I'm in 8th grade). From a starting point, I need to get a point toward a destination point. I have found several forum posts but no examples in Java.

I tried this (inside my Vector2 class):

```
public Vector2 getNextPointTowardOther(Vector2 dest, int speed) {
    if (dest == null)
        return this;
    double deltaX = dest.getX() - this.x;
    double deltaY = dest.getY() - this.y;
    double direction = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX);
    double x = this.x + (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    double y = this.y + (speed * Math.sin(direction));
    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

But it never returns a negative x or y coordinate, and it just doesn't seem to be altogether accurate.

Comment: On this very Wikipedia page, you have an exact pseudo-code implementation. The syntax is trivial, can't you see the difference between it and your code? Why the use of `atan`?

Comment: Bresenham doesn't really have something to do with this. In fact, Bresenham aims at *avoiding* the computations that you are doing here, by doing all computations with integral values and tracking the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move towards a certain destination point by a certain amount, you have to compute the *direction* from the current point towards the target point, and multiply this *direction* with the `speed` that you want to use, before adding it to the original point:

```
public Vector2 getNextPointTowardOther(Vector2 dest, int speed) {
    if (dest == null)
        return this;
    double deltaX = dest.getX() - this.x;
    double deltaY = dest.getY() - this.y;

    // Compute the distance 
    double distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY);

    // Compute the (normalized) direction 
    double dirX = deltaX / distance;
    double dirY = deltaY / distance;

    // (The vector (dirX, dirY) now has length 1.0)

    double x = this.x + speed * dirX;
    double y = this.y + speed * dirY;
    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```